# Problemas na leitura e organização de uma matriz em C

Tags: c

Eu tenho dois arquivos `.txt`, e em cada um tem uma matriz 2x8.

Eu preciso ler esses arquivos e compará-los, linha por linha, e quando a linha de ambos for igual, adicionar a um contador.

Entretanto, o problema que eu estou enfrentando é o seguinte: depois de ter lido ambas as matrizes, como eu disse, preciso compará-las, porém, o algoritmo compara todos os valores, ao invés de comparar somente linha com linha.

Segue o código que eu fiz:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include<stdlib.h>

#define Lin 8

#define Col 2

int main(){

        int i, j, cont_pontos_regra_um=0, resultado[Lin][Col], partic1[Lin][Col], cont=0;
        FILE *arq;

        arq=fopen("resultado.txt", "r");//abertura e scaneiamento do resultado.txt
        for(i=0;i<Lin;i++){
            for(j=0;j<Col;j++){
                fscanf(arq,"%d ", &resultado[i][j]);
                printf("%d ", resultado[i][j]);
        }
        }

        fclose(arq); //fechar arquivo

        arq=fopen("partic1.txt", "r");//abertura e scaneiamento do resultado.txt
        for(i=0;i<Lin;i++){
            for(j=0;j<Col;j++){
                fscanf(arq,"%d ", &partic1[i][j]);      
        }
        }
        fclose(arq); //fechar arquivo

            for(i=0;i<Lin;i++){
                for(j=0;j<Col;j++){
                    if(partic1[i][j]==resultado[i][j]){
                        cont_pontos_regra_um++;
            }   
        }
        }

        //printf("%d", cont_pontos_regra_um);

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Neste trecho:

```
for(i=0;i<Lin;i++){
    for(j=0;j<Col;j++){
        if(partic1[i][j]==resultado[i][j]){
            cont_pontos_regra_um++;
```

Faça assim:

```
for(i=0;i<Lin;i++){
    int linhas_iguais = 1; // a principio sao iguais
    for(j=0;j<Col;j++){
        if(partic1[i][j]!=resultado[i][j]){
            linhas_iguais = 0; // sao diferentes!
            break;
        }
    }
    if(linhas_iguais)
        cont_pontos_regra_um++;
}
```